# To allow external client application users to access B2C Integrated client website

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, okta, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c, okta-signin-widget

To our client website, we have implemented user authentication (using OIDC) and related user flows using Azure ADB2C. External users are successfully authenticating and accessing from our website (SPA). Also, we have implemented b2c ROPC flow for headless authentication users.

But here is a scenario, where we have a few clients who wants to access our website from the external client app. The external client application side they were using “OKTA with SSO” and tried to access our website login page, but they are failing to get the b2c token to access our website.

To achieve this, do we need to make any changes in the current b2c integrated website(my client)? Any references or integration process for our external client application should follow (external client have OKTA tenant and for SSO)?

Is there any references to assit this usecase, where the external clients apps to access other client website resources Securely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to set up B2C so that Okta is an [external IDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider).

The flow is then:

- External user (who normally authenticates with Okta) accesses your B2C application
- The login page shows an Okta button
- External user clicks the button and then authenticates with their Okta credentials (If they are set up with Okta SSO, this may happen silently)
- External user can then access your B2C application

Comment: thanks. In my client website we implement ADB2C to authenticate local accounts only. Where some of our external clients wants to access the resources of my client website. And the Client side app they were using *OKTA with SSO*, which is calling my client website. Where a group of users wants to access my client application from their client website. At our end we just implement B2C login flow to manage local accounts only. Is there any specific solution to assist the external client side applications to get access (authentication requests) to my client website with local accounts?